# How do I increase the spring tension on the idler arm on a Stock Ender 5 Pro

Tags: extruder, creality-ender-5

It has been suggested that I should increase the spring tension on the idler arm, on a Stock Ender 5 Pro, due to a problem with the extruder mangling filament during rapid retractions.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I only have ender 3 pro but if extruder works the same way you could just unscrew the bolt holding the spring in place and put some washers or a printed bush to squeeze the spring further. If you have one of those extruders with plastic arms then I've heard from some people that they could partially crack after some time, thus releasing some tension. If that's the case you might want to invest in an aluminum one.